# Finding inverse of a $3\times 4$ or $4\times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

Now I have no problem getting an inverse of a square  matrix where you just calculate
the matrix of minors, then apply matrix of co-factors and then transpose that and what you get you multiply by the determinant of the original matrix.

Now on the last test we didn't get a square  matrix; we had to find a inverse and determinant of a $3\times 4$ matrix and I was lost.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 3 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 2 & 0 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$$

How would you calculate inverse of such a matrix. The determinant is obviously 0 since
you need a square matrix to calculate a determinant.

Comment: this might help: [Pseudo Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Comment: [one-side inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices)

Comment: Non-square matrices do not have inverses.  An $m\times n$ matrix has rank at most $\min(m,n)$, and given two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the product is defined, $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B))$.  Therefore, if $A$ was an $n\times m$ matrix and be was an "inverse", one of $AB$ and $BA$ would have rank strictly smaller than it's size, which is impossible for an identity matrix.

Comment: Note that this can't possibly have a true inverse. Think about the rank-nullity theorem, for example.

Comment: I would suspect there was a "typo" on that problem. You can't say the the determinant is 0; the determinant is undefined.

Comment: The determinant is _not_ "obviously 0". As you correctly observe, non-square matrices do not have determinants. That doesn't mean the determinant is 0 -- it means that _there is no determinant at all_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is not such thing as a determinant of a non-square matrix, so it is false that "the determinant is obviously $0$" (it is *undefined*, not equal to zero, just like a limit that does not exist is not "equal to $0$", it's just undefined).

Now, when the coefficients lie in a field (the rationals, the reals, the complex numbers, for instance), non-square matrices do *not* have two-sided inverses. This is an easy application of the Rank-Nullity Theorem: if $A$ is $n\times m$, $n\neq m$, and $B$ is $m\times n$, then either $\mathrm{Null}(A)\gt 0$ or $\mathrm{Null}(B)\gt 0$ (which ever has more columns than rows). But if, say, $\mathrm{Null}(B)\gt 0$, then there is a nonzero vector $\mathbf{x}$ for which $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, and then $(AB)\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$, so $AB$ cannot be the $n\times n$ identity. A symmetric argument holds when $\mathrm{Null}(A)\gt 0$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is $n\times m$, and the matrix has "full rank" (that is, $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \min(n,m)$), then either there is (at least one) $m\times n$ matrix such that $BA=I$, *or* there is (at least one) $m\times n$ matrix $C$ such that $AC=I$. These matrices are "one-sided inverses" of $A$, and if $n\neq m$, then there will only be inverses on one side, and there will be many inverses.

The simplest way to see this is to think of $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose first that $n\lt m$ (as in your case), and the rank is $n$. That means that as a linear transformation, $A$ is onto. In particular, there are vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $A\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{e}_i$, where $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $i$th standard vector (a $1$ in the $i$th coordinate, zeros everywhere else). Now let $C$ be the $m\times n$ matrix that has $\mathbf{v}_i$ in the $i$th column.  Then $B\mathbf{e}_i = \mathbf{v}_i$, so $AC(\mathbf{e}_i) = A\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{e}_i$. Since this holds for $\mathbf{e}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{e}_m$, it follows that $AC$ is the $m\times m$ identity.

However, there are many possible choices of $\mathbf{v}_i$: since $n\lt m$, then there are *many* vectors that map to $\mathbf{e}_i$; each different choice of vectors will give you a different $C$. Of course, as in the argument above, there does *not* exist any matrix $B$ such that $BA=I$.

Now suppose that $A$ is $n\times m$ and $m\lt n$, with $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$. We view $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$, then $\mathrm{nullity}(A)=0$; so $A$ is one-to-one. that means that, since the vectors $\mathbf{e}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{e}_m$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ are linearly independent, their images $A\mathbf{e}_1,\ldots,A\mathbf{e}_m$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So we can complete this list to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A\mathbf{e}_1,\ldots,A\mathbf{e}_m,\mathbf{w}_{m+1},\ldots,\mathbf{w}_n$. Now let $B$ be the matrix that sends $A\mathbf{e}_i$ to $\mathbf{e}_i$, and maps $\mathbf{w}_j$ to any vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that you want (such a matrix always exist, for any choice of $\mathbf{w}_j$, and for any choice of images). Then $(BA)\mathbf{e}_i = B(A\mathbf{e}_i) = \mathbf{e}_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$, so $BA$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix. Again, different choices of $\mathbf{w}_j$ and/or different choices of their images give different matrices $B$, so there are *lots* of matrices $B$ that work. $B$ is *a* left inverse of $A$.

In this situation, there does not exist any matrix $C$ such that $AC=I$.

So if $A$ (with coefficients in, say, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{C}$) is not a square matrix, then it does not have an inverse, but it *will* have "one-sided inverses" on one side only.

---

(What follows is likely to be far beyond what you've studied, so you may ignore it if you want)

However, *if* the entries of the matrix lie in a noncommutative structure (coefficients in a non-commutative ring, coefficients in a division ring), then it *is* possible to find non-square matrices that have inverses. For example,let $R$ be a ring.  We can view a map $R\to R\oplus R$ as a $2\times 1$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathrm{Hom}(R,R)$, and we can view maps $R\oplus R\to R$ as $1\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathrm{Hom}(R,R)$. Since there are rings $R$ with unity $1_R\neq 0$ such that $R\cong R\oplus R$, then such an isomorphism gives us a pair of matrices, one $1\times 2$ and one $2\times 1$, with coefficients in the noncommutative ring $\mathrm{Hom}(R,R)$, which are two-sided inverses of each other.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the pseudo inverse is 
$$
\frac{1}{711}\left(
\begin{matrix}
598 & -474 & -21\\
885 & -711 & -18\\
-415 & 474 & -96\\
-296 & 237 & 96\\
\end{matrix}
\right),
$$
from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282,3,4,5%29,%282,3,5,6%29,%281,2,0,8%29%29).

Comment: I think you're missing the link you meant to include

Comment: And note that this is the pseudoinverse, not an inverse.

Comment: Thx for the comments.

Comment: But it is still not an answer to the general question "How would you calculate inverse of such a matrix?", instead if your answer was "by using WolframAlpha". In this case it would just be a bad answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau No, it's not, but still worth as a cross check AND I put Wolfram links there to make the people aware of it, because I think it's a great online tool. I just try to help people to help themselves... If you think, you have to downvote that, you're welcome.